How can I check for ToolbarItems in a Swift Test
I am trying to test my view and check for particular views inside the UI. I found something for the views inside the body, but nothing for the toolbar. See the following example:
import Foundation
import Quick
import Nimble
import ViewInspector

struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "gearshape")
                    .identifier("image")
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    Button("Press me")
                        .identifier("button")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyViewSpec: QuickSpec {
    override static func spec() {
        describe("A View") {
            var view: InspectableView<ViewType.ClassifiedView>!
            
            beforeEach {
                view = try! MyView().inspect()
            }
            it("Has a Image") {
                expect(try view.find(viewWithId: "image")).notTo(throwError())
            }
            it ("Has an item in the toolbar") {
                expect(try view.find(viewWithId: "button")).notTo(throwError()) // DOES NOT WORK
//                expect(try view.toolbar()) // CANT PASS AN ID
            }
        }
    }
}


I just want to check if the Button with the ID "button" is present, but the view can not be found.
I have tried to find a solution with Google, but unfortunately I don't find any solution for this problem. Maybe someone faced this already and has an idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance :-)

Looking at the library's tests, there is an example of what is probably the intended approach:
.toolbar(id: "abc") { ToolbarItem(id: "") { Text("") } }

followed by:
XCTAssertEqual(try sut.inspect().toolbar(1).identifier(), "abc")

